# Sequence containing number of groups on an $n$-element set

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

I know there is a sequence in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences that lists the number of non-isomorphic groups on an $n$-element set. However, I am interested in the total number of groups on an $n$-element set. Of course, there is actually a proper class of such groups, but I mean the number of groups on a fixed $n$-element set, like for example the set $\{1,...,n\}$. Is there such a sequence in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences? Of course, analogous questions could be asked about other classes of algebraic structures, like abelian groups, monoids, semigroups, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the number of "labelled groups" with $n$ elements. Here is the OEIS entry: http://oeis.org/A034383. Likewise there is an OEIS entry for "labelled monoids", etc.